# libgdx move player in 4 directions

Tags: android, libgdx

I want to move the main character when the player touch him and drag. The problem is that I can't move the chacarter in all directions (up, down, left, right). Only up and down, or left and right. But never the four with the same code.

This is the main code: the InputProcessor. I think the problem is in the touchDragged function. With this code, the player only moves to the left:

```
public class UserTouchs implements InputProcessor {
int previousY = 0;
int previousX = 0;

private Charcter character;
private GameScreen screen;
private Vector2 stageCoord;

private Stage stage;

public UserTouchs(GameScreen screen) {

    this.screen = screen;
    character= screen.getCharacter();
    stage = screen.getStage();
}

public boolean keyDown (int keycode) {
    return false;
}

public boolean keyUp (int keycode) {
    return false;
}

public boolean keyTyped (char character) {
    return false;
}

public boolean touchDown (int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
    previousY = y;

    stageCoord = stage.screenToStageCoordinates(new Vector2(x, y));
    Actor actorHit = stage.hit(stageCoord.x, stageCoord.y, true);
    if (actorHit != null)
        if(actorHit.getName()=="character"){

        }
    return true;
}

public boolean touchUp (int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
    character.straight();
    return true;
}

public boolean touchDragged (int x, int y, int pointer) {
    if (previousY > y) {
        character.down();
    } else {
        character.up();
    }
    previousY = y;

    //This isn't working well
    if (previousX > x) {
        character.left();
    } else {
        character.right();
    }
    previousX = x;
    return true;
}

public boolean mouseMoved (int x, int y) {
    return false;
}

public boolean scrolled (int amount) {
    return false;
}
```

}

If I delete the x (left and right) the player go up and down, correctly.

```
    public boolean touchDragged (int x, int y, int pointer) {
    if (previousY > y) {
        character.down();
    } else {
        character.up();
    }
    previousY = y;
    return true;
}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your character movement methods?

Comment: If it moves only to the left then I would say problem is in character.right() method. Try debugging it, put some break point, see is it called and what happen when it is.

Comment: Movement method added!

Comment: Update: solved the right movement. In CHARACTER_RIGHT I changed the this.position.x -=... for: this.position.x +=... Now the player only go left and right, never up and down (I think it's a problem of touchDragged method).

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem was the If else:

```
    public boolean touchDragged (int x, int y, int pointer) {
    // Si la Y es menor que la anterior Y, va hacia abajo
    if (previousY > y) {
        goku.down();
        //Si la Y es mayor que la que tenemos guardada, va hacia arriba
    } else if (previousY < y){
        goku.up();
        //Si la X es menos que la que tenemos guardada, vamos hacia la izquierda
    } else if (previousX > x){
        goku.left();
        //En caso contrario, el jugador va hacia la derecha
    } else {
        goku.right();
    }
    // Almacenamos ambas posiciones
    previousY = y;
    previousX = x;
    return true;
}
```